# Integrate Paypal for payment between two personal accounts

Tags: php, paypal

I've got a website selling second hand things as ebay.

I want to integrate Paypal on my website, but I don't want to get the money. 
I just want that a buyer pay the seller using Paypal.

Do you know how to integrate that ?

Thinks, and please excuse my french english !

Answer (score 0):

Personal accounts do not offer any integration or verification features, but you can point them to the correct PayPal page by populating a link with appropriate data:

`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=recipient%40email%2ecom&lc=US&item_name=test123&item_number=123&amount=50%2e00&currency_code=USD&button_subtype=services&no_note=0&tax_rate=5%2e000&shipping=10%2e00&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHostedGuest`

Also see: [PayPal Buttons](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside)

Comment: Is it possible to receive payments from credit/debit card into paypal personal account? 
I've heard about upgrading it to premier account to achieve this, but I couldn't find any way to upgrade my personal account to premier account. ( I live in Canada )